# EFfax-GTK says file does not exist...?

Tags: 19.10, ubuntu-mate, fax

So I just set up a fax station with an external modem and I'm trying to upload multiple files to send out to one number and I get the error saying the File does not exist..

I mean, it does exist, I selected them on the local drive. Am I missing something?

[image: GTK]

Comment: `efax-gtk` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=efax-gtk&searchon=names

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.... I have the packages, so why am I getting the error?